# How can I set up a vue-router navigation guard?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Laravel + Vue site that allows users to book on to training courses. A typical course URL might be `www.mysite.com/courses/a-great-course`. This is set up in my router.js file in the usual way:

```
path: '/courses/:slug',
        component: Course,
        name: 'course'
```

with the slug naturally being pulled from the database.

I have a standard vue-router catch all route defined that works fine for the first level of the URL and diverts to a Not Found page, but if I ask for a course that doesn't exist - `www.mysite.com/courses/wrong-course` - it still loads the page and just sits on the loading animation.

As I understand it I need to implement a navigation guard but I'm completely confused as to how to do that - it seems all the online examples deal with situations like checking if a user is authenticated in the Store.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: The path that you've set up `/courses/:slug` is going to match `courses/wrong-course`, so from what you've told us everything is behaving as it should.  Why do you want to set up a navigation guard?  Is it to prevent un-authenticated users from accessing a page, or do you not know what your routes in your app are...?

Comment: @wes because if a user visits a route using a slug that doesn't exist, it shows a blank page. I have figured out a solution - the navigation guard grabs all the relevant slugs from the database and compares the entered slug to them to see if it's valid.